# Transferir todos os arquivos de um diretório

Tags: c++, socket, diretório

Tenho uma aplicação que transferi arquivos via socket, porém de um em um.
Preciso que essa aplicação transfira um diretório inteiro.

Devo fornecer um diretório, **EX: "c:\users\Servidor\PASTA_DOWNLOAD"**

e então o programa deve transferir via socket todos os arquivos contidos nesse diretório, alguém pode me dar algumas informações sobre como eu devo proceder?

Comment: Assumindo que o teu código está estruturado, uma ideia para resolver o problema passa por: 1) Ler os nomes dos ficheiros nesse directorio; 2) executar o codigo que já tens num ciclo para processar cada um dos ficheiros lido no passo 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho um projeto com algo parecido com o que você quer, da uma olhada

```
  int HYPNOS_Remote_Manip::HYPNOS_FOLDER_DOWNLOAD(std::string dir_remote, Socket_Setup &socket_setup)
{
    HANDLE dir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file_data;

    if ((dir = FindFirstFile((dir_remote + "\\*").c_str(), &file_data)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 1; /* No files found */

    do 
    {
        std::string file_name = file_data.cFileName;
        std::string full_file_name = dir_remote + "\\" + file_name;
        const bool is_directory = (file_data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0;

        if (file_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        if (is_directory)
            continue;

        if (file_name == "desktop.ini")
            continue;

        int iResult = send(socket_setup.ConnectSocket, file_name.c_str(), strlen(file_name.c_str()), 0);  // Meio obvio, aqui você envia o nome do arquivo para o servidor 
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            break;
        else
            HYPNOS_FILE_DOWNLOAD(full_file_name, socket_setup); // aqui é a função onde você passa o diretório do arquivo em que será enviado para o servidor
    } while (FindNextFile(dir, &file_data));

    FindClose(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o formato do endereço do teu diretório, creio que você esta num sistema Windows. As bibliotecas para C++ para procura em diretório são: [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Veja aqui um exemplo simplório de uma busca em um diretório:

```
HANDLE hArquivo;
WIN32_FIND_DATA arquivo;

hArquivo = FindFirstFile("c:\\users\\Servidor\\PASTA_DOWNLOAD\\*", &arquivo);

if ( hFile )
{
    do
    {
        String strNomeDoArquivo = arquivo.cFileName

        //Lance teu código de cópia aqui

    }while (FindNextFile(hArquivo, &arquivo) != 0)

    CloseHandle(hArquivo)
}
```

Vale lembrar que este código não seria portável para outros tipos de SO.

Fonte: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)